# How to call a service from another service in docker swarm

Tags: docker, flask, docker-swarm

I have created 2 services in docker swarm using images `app1` and `app2`, where service app1 makes a call to app2 but in docker swarm service app1 can't connect to service app2 at `app2:5000` (`<service-name>:<port>`) getting error `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`, on the contrary If I create normal container (without docker swarm) then app1 can easily call app2 at `app2:5000` (`<container-name>:<port>`)

Inside docker swarm following commands have been used to create service

```
$ sudo docker service create --name app1 -p 5001:5000 app1:latest
$ sudo docker service create --name app2 -p 5002:5000 app2:latest
```

Outside docker swarm following commands are used to run containers

```
$ sudo docker-compose build
$ sudo docker-compose up
```

Code used to build Images app1 and app2 are shown below

[image]

**app.py (App1)**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def func1():
    return jsonify('This is App #1')

@app.route('/call')
def func2():
    res = requests.get('http://app2:5000/call')
    res = res.json()
    return jsonify(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

**app.py (App2)**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def func1():
    return jsonify('This is App #2')

@app.route('/call')
def func2():
    return jsonify('Call to App2 is Successful')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  
  app1:
    build: ./app1         
    image: "app1:latest"   
    container_name: app1
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    networks:
      - net1
  
  app2:
    build: ./app2
    image: "app2:latest"
    container_name: app2
    ports:
      - "5002:5000"
    networks:
      - net1

networks:
  net1:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting services in the same network fixed the issue